# how to scroll the horizontal bar in a grid using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

How to scroll the horizontal bar in a grid using selenium. This should be repeated in multiple selections. I have to select the value and click submit. I have to check all the column headers. But, there are 46 columns. Please help. I am unable to move it.

```
List<WebElement> gridlabellist = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gview_list']/div[3]/div/table/thead/tr/th"));
List<String> all_gridlabellist=new ArrayList<>();
Thread.sleep(1000);
int gl;
System.out.println(gridlabellist.size());
for(gl=0; gl<gridlabellist.size(); gl++)
{
    String gridlabelname=gridlabellist.get(gl).getText();
    boolean dislabel=gridlabellist.get(gl).isEnabled();
    //System.out.println(labelname);

    if((gridlabelname != null) && (gridlabelname.length()!=0) && dislabel)
    {
        System.out.println("\nGrid Label Names displayed: "  + gridlabelname);

        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(2000,0)");  
        System.out.println("\nGrid Label Names displayed: " +gridlabelname);
    }
    all_gridlabellist.add(gridlabellist.get(gl).getText());
}
```

[image: grid]

Comment: I have tried with boolean dislabel=gridlabellist.get(gl).isEnabled(); also tried earlier with "boolean dislabel=gridlabellist.get(gl).isdisabled();"

Comment: Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

its a very old question but still relevant enough to answer with alternative ways, another way to solve this problem is to zoom, zoom to 50-30% or even 10%; this will load all the columns and then read them using xpath.

Comment: Do you have sample code by which we can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach & test if it works for you

`WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//blah-blah"));
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
 js.executeScript(
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", scroll);`

Comment: thanks nandesh for reply but, I have 30+columns. I have to collect all the column header. As per your reply, I have to collect per page. is there any other way?